# Does the Bavarian Illuminati make a privileged attack in addition to their two actions?

Tags: illuminati

The special ability of the Bavarian Illuminati allows them to make a privileged attack for the cost of 5MB. Is this a free action?

Comment: Welcome to B&CG!  I'm not sure it matters for this question, but I know there have been a couple different editions of Illuminati over the years.  Can you clarify which one you have?

Comment: Thanks, Pat. Here is a URL for the version I was refering to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminati_(game)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, the Bavarian Illuminati's special attack is not a free action.**

It is not listed as an example free action in the list on page 7 of the [rules](http://www.sjgames.com/illuminati/img/illuminati_rules.pdf).  It's function is built into the regular attacks used.  Note that the only mention of the special power in the rules section is inside of the **Interference** section on page 7.

The Bavarian's privileged attack is simply a way for them to avoid paying the usual cost to make an attack privileged. Instead of Discarding a special card, they can spend $5 once/turn to make an attack privileged.

This does not mean that the groups participating in the attack are exempt from the general rule that each group may only participate in one attack per turn.